# Ping Equivalent for SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, sshd

Is there an equivalent to running  `ping $HOST` but for the ssh daemon? Just to check if it's running, no attempt to log in as a specific user or validate with credentials

Something like

`DAEMON_UP=$(sshping $HOST | process_output)`

Comment: If the daemon is running on the default port, one could scan port 22 to check to see if it is active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use `nc` (netcat) for this:

```
$ nc -zv 127.0.0.1 22
localhost [127.0.0.1] 22 (ssh) open
```

The `-z` option is "zero-I/O mode" specifically for scanning.

The `-v` option means "verbose" and actually causes the output to be generated; without this option only the exit status will indicate whether the port is open or not (0 = yes, 1 = no). This makes it easy to use this in scripting:

```
if nc -z 127.0.0.1 22; then
    echo "ssh daemon is listening on port 22"
else
    echo "ssh daemon is not listening on port 22"
fi
```

Comment: For anyone on Windows, you can [download and install `nmap`](https://nmap.org/download.html), a "network map" utility, which contains `ncat`, a modern reimplementation of netcat, and run the same thing. Ex: `ncat -zv bitbucket.org 22` will tell you [if your network admins are blocking your port 22 traffic to clone things on Bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76918674/4561887).

Answer (score 4):

one way is to use **nmap** (in the example below I checked if port 22 was open on localhost)

```
nmap -p 22 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

how about telnet ?

```
telnet [IP or hostname] port
```

example

```
telnet myhost 22
```

Comment: you might need to press return/enter a few times to get out if it connects, use nmap.

Comment: You should be able to get out with (Ctrl)+`]`, `quit`, (Enter).

Answer (score 0):

```
# ssh root@client1 exit > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Reachable" || echo "NotReachable"

# ssh root@192.168.1.100 exit > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Reachable" || echo "NotReachable"

# ssh root@client2 exit > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Reachable" || echo "NotReachable"
```

Below is the perfect for loop code for ssh connection test,
you just need to replace user name and and include list of servers need to do **SSH ping** test in the `hosts_inventory.txt` file.

```
# for host in `cat hosts_inventory.txt`; do ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o LogLevel=ERROR root@$host exit > /dev/null && echo "$host Reachable" || echo "$host NotReachable"; done
```

Below is the Expected SSH ping test output

```
client Reachable
server Reachable
192.168.1.102 Reachable
192.168.1.101 Reachable
client Reachable
server Reachable
192.168.1.102 Reachable
192.168.1.101 Reachable
client Reachable
server Reachable
192.168.1.102 Reachable
192.168.1.101 Reachable
server1 NotReachable
client1 NotReachable
```